# Deploying production org configuration to new dev org

Tags: deployment, metadata-api

I'm trying to copy over all the metadata(config, workflow, objects, etc...) from a production org to an unrelated empty dev org however I'm running into issues with the deployment. I had to wild card everything inside package.xml to retrieve from the source org and that seems to run fine without errors. When I deploy to the new dev org I'm hitting the maximum limit for a deploy(Is this an issue with wildcarding everything in package.xml?). I can't split up the package as most of the files are dependent on each other and I'm hoping to not have to manually check through each of them. Is there a better way to copy over production org metadata to a new dev org? I'm using sfdx for deployment and retrieval right now. I haven't used the ant tool as I assumed I would run into the same issue of reaching the maximum limit.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have a limit of 10,000 components per deployment. You will want to exclude certain types, like Dashboards, Reports, Email Templates, and so on. The best way to deploy is in phases. You can do this in pretty broad strokes with some planning. CustomObject and CustomLabel can go first, then various auth methods (NamedCredentials, etc), then all code (Visualforce, Apex, etc), then all flexipages, processes, workflows, etc, and finally Email Templates and Reports if you want them. This would also be a good exercise for planning out Unlocked Packages, since they share the same limitations. As an example, in our org, we have 34,000 artifacts in our code repository, and I've managed to recreate nearly the entire org in a Scratch Org with a bit of work (a few days, I think). We're not actively using the Unlocked Packages (yet), but we'll be moving there after summer dies down and our business has some breathing room to work on niceties.